# "Unknown runtime error" in IE

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, sdk, internet-explorer-8

I'm using Facebook JS SDK and it's working perfectly in all browsers except Internet explorer 7/8 (of course). Console outputs the following error:

> Unknown runtime error: all.js, line 128 character 3067

Line 128, character 3067 points to this in all.js:

```
this._element.innerHTML='';
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Edit: 
HTML surrounding login button:
http://pastebin.com/ZSeMgRiJ

Comment: This is sometimes caused by invalid HTML code. Could you please show the html you are using with the Facebook SDK.

Comment: Sure. I added the html surrounding the login button to the question. However, we get the js error also in pages where the login button is not present, we're simply including the facebook api in javascript.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you include the script at the end of `body` tag? Or in the `head` tag?